# Deriving the response amplitude

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For the system:

$z''(t)-\delta z'(t)+\kappa^2z(t)=Asin(wt)$

 How can you derive the response amplitude $R$?

 (I have figured out that the solution is of the form $z_p(t)= Rsin(wt+\psi)$, however I am unsure of how to cancel out the trigonometric terms)

Comment: Oops, sorry I should have specified, $\kappa , \delta$, $A$ and $R$ are all constants.

Comment: The easiest way is the method of complex amplitudes: you solve $z''(t) - \delta z'(t) +\kappa^2 z(t) = A e^{i\omega t}$ searching solution in form $Re^{i(\omega t + \phi)}$ and from this you will find both amplitude and phase response characteristics.

Comment: Is it legitimate to replace $Asin(wt) $ with $ Ae^{iwt}$ though since the complex term will have a cosine?

Comment: Sure, it's one of the properties of linear ODEs ${\mathcal L} z(t) = c(t)$ where ${\mathcal L}$ has only real-valued coefficients or functions. If $z(t)$ solves such equation with complex-valued $c(t)$, then ${\rm Re}\; z(t)$ solves ${\mathcal L} z(t) = {\rm Re}\; c(t)$; the same holds for ${\rm Im}\; z(t)$ and ${\rm Im}\; c(t)$.